# Pattern for handling errors and warnings

Tags: java

Is there a good design pattern for Java for methods that can produce both errors and warnings, both of which should be communicated to the method caller (and eventually the UI)?  What I'm doing right now is just returning the errors, warnings, and result as a single object, but that leads to convoluted and error-prone C-style error handling, since I lose the convenience of exception propagation.

I would use exceptions if I didn't have to handle warnings, but I do have to handle warnings, and throwing exceptions would have two downsides:

A. Errors and warnings would not be communicated homogenously (not a big deal)

B. I would have to handle warnings in two different code paths (the case in which an exception is thrown, and the case in which the function returns normally) in all client code

Comment: Design pattern depends in part on how you're going to display those messages to the user, but I've been using the `'log4j` library. I know folks hate off-site references, but you might want to look at its API and see if that's a pattern you consider worth adopting.

Comment: The normal mechanism for returning "terminating" errors in Java is exceptions.

Comment: Actually, the normal mechanism for many errors is exceptions, with them being caught and handled otherwise (eg logging) if they shouldn't cause termination in this specific case.

Comment: @Licks That would be sufficient if the method could only produce errors, but it can also produce warnings, and ideally, they'd be communicated homogenously, since the UI in this case is rendering them homogeneously.

Comment: An example of a specific problem, the error-and-or-warning it's supposed to trigger, and how the client should see/recieve that notification would be most helpful. And how "two different code paths" fit in...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare custom Exceptions, throw them using `throw new MyException();` and catch them like this:

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException() {}
    public MyException(String message) { super(message); }
}

void foo() throws MyException {
    /* ... */
    throw new MyException("MyString");
}

void bar() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (MyException me) {
        /* Error handling here */
    }
}
```

Edit:
Alternatively you could declare an errno-like variable in your class and check it after each function call or pass an array to the function like this:

```
void foo() {
    int[] errors = {0, 0};
    bar(errors);
    if(errors[0] != 0) /* error handling */
    if(errors[1] != 0) /* warning handling */
}

void bar(int[] errors) {
    /* ... */
    errors[0] = 42; /* error code */
    errors[1] = 1337; /* warning code */;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the "warnings" portion of my use case

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you wanted to throw errors AND warnings, but you might check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, using Exceptions for program flow is an anti-pattern - don't do it. Exceptions are for the exceptional, not for routine situations.

I would return a value object that contains a List of `Problem`, which have a message and a severity.